# Multiply list of lists at different levels in R

Tags: r, list

I would like to multiply the numeric values two levels deep in a list by the values one level deep in another list in R. For example, consider the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

weights <- list(a = list(1, 3, 8), b = list(2, 4), c = list(5, 2, 8, 0.5)) 
multiplier <- list(0.5, 0.25, 0.10)
```

This is the basic idea of what I'd like to do, but this does not work.....

```
result <- weights * multiplier
```

I would like to produce a list of lists with the same structure as the list titled "weights" but with each variable multiplied by the value in the "multiplier" list.

My desired result is:

```
result <- list(a = list(0.5, 1.5, 4), b = list(0.5, 1), c = list(0.5, 0.2, 0.8, 0.05))
```

I feel like this should be a relatively easy thing to do, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map2` to loop over the `list`, and as 'weights' is a nested list, `unlist` it, multiply with each corresponding element from 'multiplier' list, and `relist` it back to `list`

```
library(purrr)
map2(weights, multiplier,  ~ relist(unlist(.x) * .y, skeleton = .x))
```

---

The similar option in `base R` is with `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y) relist(unlist(x) * y, skeleton = x), weights, multiplier)
```

---

Or another option is to `stack` it to a two column data.frame, and then do the multiplication after `rep`licating to make lengths same and then `relist`

```
relist(with(stack(weights), values *
          rep(unlist(multiplier), table(ind))), weights)
```